# :NoMethodError: undefined method `devise' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):

Tags: devise

I have searched the similar questions but I'm not able to run rails generate devise:install.  I get the following:

> C:\Users\Royal and Carla\Desktop\Schwiftology>rails generate devise:install
>   Could not find generator 'devise:install'. Maybe you meant 'assets', 'test_unit:job' or 'scss:assets'
>   Run `rails generate --help` for more options.

Comment: have you restated your server?

Comment: did you run migrations?

Comment: did you bundle?

Comment: Yes, to restarting the server, yes to running a migration, and yes to doing a Bundle Install,,,,

Comment: In the the list of Generators there is no Devise listed.

Comment: have you done `rails generate devise:install`

Comment: >Please choose a generator below.

Rails:
  assets
  channel
  controller
  generator
  helper
  integration_test
  jbuilder
  job
  mailer
  migration
  model
  resource
  scaffold
  scaffold_controller
  system_test
  task

Coffee:
  coffee:assets

Js:
  js:assets

TestUnit:
  test_unit:generator
  test_unit:plugin

Comment: Rails Generate Devise:Install can't find the Generator please see above.

Comment: do you have the  gem in your Gemfile

Comment: Yes, I have it installed.

Comment: I wish I could help more. but I am stuck myself

Comment: I'd recommend you to purge your gems and install it again. Are you using `rvm` or `rbenv`?

Comment: Actually, I re-ran it and it finally worked.  I'm wondering if it was an issue due to the fact I'm running Rails on Windows?  A few ppl stated to not run Rails on Windows.